# How can I enable XeTeX to typeset partial Hangeul (Korean)?

Tags: xetex, luatex, cjk, xecjk

When I compile the following code containing partial Korean Hangeul characters with XeTeX, the characters are not displayed properly. When compiling with LuaTeX they are set overlapping each other, as they should.

What is the reason for the different output? I would prefer to use XeTeX, but can I enable it to work with these characters as well?

```
\documentclass{scrarticle}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

\ifxetex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{xeCJK}
    \setCJKmainfont{Batang}
\else\ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{luatexko}
\fi\fi

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\noV}{{\color{black!20}ᅟᅳ}}

\begin{document}
    
    Only works in Lua\TeX: \noV ᆯ 
    
    Only works in Lua\TeX: \noV ᆼ 
    
    Full characters always work: 한글
    
\end{document}
```

**XeTeX Output:** 
[image]

**LuaTeX Output:** 
[image]

---

## Edit:

`\color` does not seem to be the culprit

```
...
\begin{document}
    
    Still only works in Lua\TeX: ᅟᅳᆯ
    
    Still only works in Lua\TeX: ᅟᅳᆼ
    % Stack.EX can compose them too :o
    
    Full characters always work: 한글
    
\end{document}
```

**XeTeX Output:** 
[image: ![enter image description here]

**LuaTeX Output:** 
[image]

---

Since this editor already displays the partial chars in combination, for clarity, I'll list the characters separately:
the filler "ᅟ" (U+115F)
followed by the vowel "ᅳ" (U+1173)
followed by "ᆯ" resp. "ᆼ" (U+11AF and U+110B)

Comment: The color command is the problem. `\color` insert whatsits between the chars and so disable ligatures and similar. xetex has no tools to handle this. So either don't use a color, or use lualatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The problem remains without ``\color`` as well. I've updated my question to include more detail. Instead of overlapping the composite symbols, XeTeX prints the same result as if I had used single symbols like ㄹ (U+3139) instead.

Comment: I don't have your font but I tried with `\setCJKmainfont{UnBatang.ttf}` and it looks ok. I have a current texlive 2021 on windows.

Comment: Stupid me, blaming poor XeTeX... Yes, the font was the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the font was the issue and simple Batang doesn't contain the composite characters. After reading Ulrike's comment I simply put

```
\setCJKmainfont{UnBatang}
```

instead and everything worked fine, with and without color.

Comment: I was just about to comment that but refreshed to see the updates—I could see in the two samples that the Korean in the two samples was set in different fonts and wondered if that might be the problem.